# Microsoft Graph Api Mail Send Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send e-mail using graph API in the software. The message section of the e-mail I send is full, and there does not seem to be any problem there. But when sending it gives the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". After passing the Task.Delay method, I get this error. What am I doing wrong? I couldn't figure it out.
This code :

```
try
{

  
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


    //var url = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "EWS", configName: "EwsUrl");
    var username = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "EWS", configName: "Email");
    var password = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "EWS", configName: "Password");
    var fromAddress = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "SMTP", configName: "From");
    //var traceEnabled = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "EWS", configName: "TraceEnabled");
    var tenantId = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "EWS", configName: "TenantId");
    var clientId = GetMailConfig(configGroup: "EWS", configName: "ClientId");
    var access_token = "";
    var redirect_uri = "https://example.example.com/";
    var clienSecretId = "This is secret key";
    //var scopes = new[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send" };
    var scopes = new[] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };



    var pca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clienSecretId)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
    .Build();



    var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
    {

        try
        {


            var result = await pca.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            

            request.Headers.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            
        }

    });


    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    var message = new Message
    {
        Subject = mailTemplate.Subject,
        From = new Recipient() { EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress { Address = "example@example.com" } },
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html,
            Content = mailTemplate.Body
        },

    };

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();


    var attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();

    if (mailTemplate.Cc != null && mailTemplate.Cc.Any())
        message.CcRecipients = mailTemplate.Cc.Select(x => new Recipient()
        {
            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
            {
                Address = x
            }
        });



    if (mailTemplate.To != null && mailTemplate.To.Any())
        message.ToRecipients = mailTemplate.To.Select(x => new Recipient()
        {
            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
            {
                Address = x
            }
        });

    var saveToSentItems = false;


    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            await graphClient.Me
           .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
           .Request()
           .PostAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            
        }

    });


}
catch (Exception exp)
{

    isSentMailSuccess = false;
}
return isSentMailSuccess;
```

```
 
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            await graphClient.Me
           .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
           .Request()
           .PostAsync();
```

This code has exception.

I examined the code lines one by one, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Which exact line throws the exception? Which object is null? Can you [edit] your post to shorten your code example? See [mre].

Comment: Remove the await.  Delay is not an async method that returns an object.  await needs something returned to continue.

Comment: @gunr2171 I added exception row

Comment: Please share the stack trace. Try to debug your code to be sure that graphClient is not null.

Comment: If you use the Graph API to send email, you need to ensure that you have the necessary permissions and that the message object is configured correctly. You use graphClient.Me.SendMail(...), which sends an email on behalf of the currently authenticated user. So you must ensure that you have the necessary permissions and that your message object has the required fields correctly populated

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `/me` endpoint (`graphClient.Me.xxx`) when using authentication with client id and client credentials.

Your are not authenticated as any user.

So, either change the code to

```
await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"]
           .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
           .Request()
           .PostAsync();
```

or change the authentication to [get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Also the stack trace would be useful, it's not clear what exactly is null and throws the exception.